# Nested Cross Validation performance on each Sequential Feature Selection subset

Tags: cross-validation, feature-selection, data-leakage

I want to get cross-validated performance values of my model after hyperparameter tuning and sequential feature selection on *each* feature subset. Following [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html), I want to use an outer-CV where in each fold I fit the GridSearch with SFS and then re-train the best model on each identified subset. Something like this (pseudocode):

```py
pipe_for_sfs = Pipeline(
  "scaler": scaler,
  "model": model,
)
sfs = SFS(estimator=pipe_for_sfs)
pipe_for_grid_search = Pipeline(
  "scaler": scaler,  
  "sfs": sfs,
  "model", model,
)
grid_search = GridSearch(estimator=pipe_for_grid_search)

performances = {x:[] for x in range(1:10)}
for fold in split(data):
  X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = apply_fold(data)
  grid_search.fit()

  sfs_obj = grid_search.best_estimator_.named_steps["sfs"]

  for subset in range(1, 10)
    features = sfs_obs.get_feature_ids[subset]

    pipe = clone(grid_search.best_estimator_)
    pipe.fit(X_train.iloc[:, features], y_train)

    y_pred = pipe.predict(X_test.iloc[:, features])
    score = some_scoring(y_test, y_pred)

    performances[subset].append(score)
```

Does this approach make sense, is it save data-leakage-wise?

Comment: "on each feature subset." *why* do you want to do that?  Cross-validation is best viewed as a method for evaluating a *procedure* for fitting a model, not of the model itself, so looking at models from individual folds is not usually that helpful.  Better to analyse the final model build by that procedure on the whole dataset.  BTW I would advise against feature selection if it is for improving performance rather than because identifying useful features is a key goal of the analysis.  Regularisation is a better approach in most cases.

Comment: In my use-case it's important to reduce the number of input variables to evaluate new cases, I want to know how far I can reduce it without large performance losses. What do you mean by "analyse the final model built by that procedure on the whole dataset"?

Comment: After performing cross validation it is normal to rebuild the model using the entire dataset as that will normally perform better than any of the models constructed in each fold (as it has a  larger training set).

Comment: I was wondering what you meant by "analyse" in this case, how would I use this model to analyse performance at each number of features? Or did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: As I said, cross-validation is a method for evaluating the performance of a method for fitting a model (which would include feature selection).  So after estimating performance by cross-validation, you repeat that entire method for all of the data (including the feature selection step) to produce the final model.  If you perform model or feature selection by minimising cross-validation performance, it will give an optimistically biased performance estimate - see https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf use nested cross-validation if you need a reliable performance estimate.